# Getting build artifacts in right folder when using sbt-web-scalajs

Tags: sbt, scala.js, playscalajs

I have a ScalaJS + Play project with an SBT build file, and am using amongst others the plugin `sbt-web-scalajs`. There is a total of 4 subprojects in my `build.sbt`. Here's the beginning of that file:

```
import sbt.Keys.libraryDependencies

val myScalaVersion     = "2.13.1"
val scalaTestPlusVersion = "5.1.0"
val scalaJsDomVersion  = "1.0.0"
val scalaTagsVersion   = "0.8.6"
val scalatagsrxVersion = "0.5.0"
val circeVersion       = "0.13.0"
val rosHttpVersion     = "3.0.0"
val quillVersion       = "3.5.2"
val pgDriverVersion    = "42.2.5"
val scriptsVersion     = "1.1.4"
val apacheCommonsMailV = "1.5"

useJCenter := true

scalaVersion in ThisBuild := myScalaVersion

scalaJSStage in Global := FullOptStage

lazy val backend = (project in file("backend")).settings(commonSettings).settings(
  scalaJSProjects := Seq(frontend, sec_frontend),
  pipelineStages in Assets := Seq(scalaJSPipeline),
  pipelineStages := Seq(gzip),
  pipelineStages := Seq(scalaJSProd, gzip),
  compile in Compile := ((compile in Compile) dependsOn scalaJSPipeline).value,
  scalaJSStage := FullOptStage,
  isDevMode in scalaJSPipeline := false,

  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.vmunier" %% "scalajs-scripts" % scriptsVersion,
    jdbc,
    evolutions,
    "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % pgDriverVersion,
    "org.apache.commons" % "commons-email" % apacheCommonsMailV,
    "io.getquill" %% "quill-jdbc" % quillVersion,
    "io.circe" %% "circe-core" % circeVersion,
    "io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % circeVersion,
    "io.circe" %% "circe-parser" % circeVersion,
    "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % scalaTestPlusVersion % "test",
    guice,
    specs2 % Test
  )
).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
 .dependsOn(sharedJvm)

lazy val frontend = (project in file("frontend")).settings(commonSettings).settings(
  scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := true,
  scalaJSStage := FullOptStage,

  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % scalaJsDomVersion,
    "com.lihaoyi" %%% "scalatags" % scalaTagsVersion,
    "io.circe" %%% "circe-core" % circeVersion,
    "io.circe" %%% "circe-generic" % circeVersion,
    "io.circe" %%% "circe-parser" % circeVersion,
    "com.github.nondeterministic" %%% "roshttp" % rosHttpVersion,
    "com.timushev" %%% "scalatags-rx" % scalatagsrxVersion
  ),
).enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin, ScalaJSWeb)
 .dependsOn(sharedJs)

[...]
```

When I build and then run my project, I have the following artifacts, needed to execute the generated JavaScript code, correctly created:

```
./frontend/target/scala-2.13/frontend-opt.js
./backend/target/web/classes/main/META-INF/resources/webjars/backend/0.15.0-alpha2/frontend-opt.js
./backend/target/web/public/main/frontend-opt.js
```

**However, a problem arises when I try to update the plugin `sbt-web-scalajs` to 1.1 or 1.2 as it no longer supports the `isDevMode` flag used in my `backend` subproject.** That is, if I compile and run my project without it, only one of the three files above is generated:

```
./frontend/target/scala-2.13/frontend-opt.js
```

And my ScalaJS/JavaScript frontend fails to load, subsequently. I looked through the documentation of the `sbt-web-scalajs` project, which says that all is controlled now via `scalaJSStage`, but it doesn't seem to get me the required output files in the required project directories.

In other words, `isDevMode` seemingly did more than just control whether `fastOpt` or `fullOpt` is run, and it is unclear to me how to get the old functionality back.